# Filter system fields from Sharepoint ListItemCollection c#

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I have this problem where I would like to filter out some unwanted fields from a ListItemCollection. Specifically I have an IEnumerable with several field names to include when displaying my data. At the moment when I load the client context for my ListItemCollection I use a static Linq expression to get the fields I need. Like this:

```
  clientContext.Load(collListItem,
            items => items.Include(
                item => item["Permissions"],
                item => item["User"]));
```

This works for me at the moment but when I will be adding custom fields later on through csom I’m afraid this approach will not suffice. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it suffices now, and why it would with more (custom?) fields? What makes the difference?

Comment: Later on down the line, a user will be able to add fields to the list. Coding it this way would require me to write every single field into the include Linq.
Instead I have an IEnumerable that gets all of the fields from the current list. I just need a way of using it in the Linq.

Comment: Could you post a msdn url of that `Load` function? What is the type of `items` in your given example?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPListTasks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry it took so long to reply, I was on training. Anyway I managed to solve the problem using the following syntax.

```
foreach (string li in fieldsToDisplay)
{
    clientContext.Load(collListItem,
        items => items.Include(
            item => item[li]));
}
```

Where the variable fieldsToDisplay is a generic list containing the names of each field I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to filter the `ListItem`s in the `ListItemCollection`.

Is this of any help? You could dynamically construct `allowedFields`

```
        var lic = new ListItemCollection();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var fieldName = string.Format("field {0}", i);
            var fieldValue = string.Format("Value {0}", i);
            lic.Add(new ListItem(fieldName, fieldValue));
        }

        var allowedFields = new List<string>
        {
            "field 1",
            "field 4"
        };

        var listItems = lic.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => allowedFields.Contains(i.Text));
```

This will result in 2 items.

or in the `void Load<T>(T clientObject, params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] retrievals) where T : ClientObject` format

```
        var func = new Func<ListItemCollection, Object>
        (collection => 
            lic.Cast<ListItem>()
            .Where(i => allowedFields.Contains(i.Text))
        );

        Load(new ClientObject(), o => func);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following options

**Option 1**

*Omit* `retrievals` parameter for [ClientRuntimeContext.Load method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536388.aspx), for example:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);

ctx.Load(item);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Option 2**

Specify field names dynamically as demonstrated below:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);

var fields = list.Fields;
ctx.Load(fields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var fieldNames = fields.Where(f => !f.FromBaseType).Select(f => f.InternalName).ToList(); //field names to retrieve: only user defined fields 
ctx.Load(item, fieldNames.Select(fieldName => (Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>) (i => i[fieldName])).ToArray());
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```